# Como fazer um SELECT MySQL somando valores de diversos IDs de uma tabela?

Tags: mysql

Olá!

Eu tenho duas tabelas: uma onde registro entradas e outra onde tenho um cadastro das formas de pagamento. Quando eu registro um valor na tabela de entrada, eu coloco o ID de forma de Pgto e esse ID corresponde ao ID da minha tabela de formas de pagamento.

Meu código SELECT é esse:

```
SELECT SUM(r_entradas.entrada_valor) AS Valor,c_forma_pgto.forma_nome AS Forma FROM r_entradas
INNER JOIN c_forma_pgto ON r_entradas.forma_id = c_forma_pgto.forma_id
WHERE log_data = CURDATE()
ORDER BY r_entradas.forma_id ASC
```

Eu estou tentando filtrar essa soma, pra que venha mostrar de forma distinta a soma respectiva de cada ID. Por exemplo:

80 | Dinheiro

50 | Crédito

Só que nesse meu código atual, ele acaba atribuindo uma forma qualquer e mostrando o total. Ex:

130 | Crédito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa utilizar o GROUP BY para que a soma ocorra de acordo com cada forma de pagamento. Exemplo:

```
SELECT 
   SUM(r_entradas.entrada_valor) AS Valor, 
   c_forma_pgto.forma_nome AS Forma 
  FROM r_entradas
 INNER JOIN c_forma_pgto ON r_entradas.forma_id = c_forma_pgto.forma_id
 WHERE log_data = CURDATE()
 GROUP BY c_forma_pgto.forma_nome
 ORDER BY r_entradas.forma_id ASC
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado!